# woocommerce_order_status_processing not triggered from customers end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to connect my code to the point where a customer has paid in WooCommerce. Because of different statements that woocommerce_payment_complete does not (always) work, I am now trying to connect to the woocommerce_order_status_processing hook.
When I create an order as a customer, it shows up as processing in the backend. All e-mails are send (to the shop-owner and to the customer), but my code is not triggered.
When I edit an order in the backend and set it to processing, the code does get triggered.

I have tried several hooks: woocommerce_payment_complete, woocommerce_order_status_completed in combination with a plugin to automatically set orders to completed, woocommerce_order_status_changed, all featuring the same behavior.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'um_versio_api_create');
function um_versio_api_create() {
     error_log('payment complete');
}
```

When I create an order as a customer, it shows up as processing in the backend. All e-mails are send (to the shop-owner and to the customer), but my code is not triggered.
When I edit an order in the backend and set it to processing, the code does get triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, writing things down helps in getting it clear...

I had the mentioned code in a piece of code that was triggered only for admin :-)

Thanks to everyone who read it anyway